Azure App Service gives "This page isn't working" after adding app-service as a user to Azure Sql Database
I am building a .NET app that is just endpoints for front end to access a database that is in Azure SQL Database. Locally it runs without problems, connecting to the Azure SQL Database with a connection string.
When I try to host it in an Azure App Service I use a managed Identity for the App Service to authenticate. Then I got the SQL-Exception "Login failed for user ''" discussed here.
When I did as discussed there and added a user for my App-Service to the database. I instead just get
"This page isn’t working" when trying to access the page of the App-Service. And in console: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"
Even if I remove the user again from my database the problem remains. But if I create a new database and point to that. I am back at "Login failed for user ''".
What can be the cause of this and why can't I see a detailed error message even if I have set
ASPNETCORE_DETAILEDERRORS to true as environment variable.
I have set the "Allow access to Azure services" to allow it.
Edit:
In Access Control my App-Service Identity has the role of SQL DB Contributor
I am not using any groups as they are doing in the question I have linked to. But I have tried setting my App Service Identity to admin of SQL Server without any difference in result (which was expected as a user shouldn't have to be the admin)
I don't get any traces in my Application Insights and Application Logging in Log Stream don't give me more than 500 - Internal Error

How is your DB connection string looking like in production? And what kind of managed Identity? User or System?

Managed Identity is System kind.
Connection string is on the form
Server=;Initial Catalog=;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;Authentication="Active Directory Default";

Did you add the Managed Identity user to any roles in SQL DB?

I've made it data reader and data writer with
ALTER ROLE DB_DATAREADER ADD MEMBER 
ALTER ROLE DB_DATAWRITER ADD MEMBER 

You may need to add the IP address of the App service under the SQL database firewall rules.
